# Cygwin make problems

Tags: makefile, cygwin

i trying to cross-compile using cygwin make, but this rule doesn't work,

$(HDIR)/%F.h: $(SDIR)/%F.ice $(SLICE2CPP) $(SLICEPARSERLIB) ,

i get 
Make *** No rule to make target `../../include/Ice/PropertiesF.h'

The same rule works fine when build under Linux

Any ideas? a bug in cygwin make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting this just above that rule:

```
$(info HDIR: $(HDIR))
ifneq ($(HDIR), ../../include/Ice)
$(info HDIR is not what you think it is)
endif
$(info SDIR: $(SDIR))
```

Try making `../../include/ice/PropertiesF.h` again, then verify that `PropertiesF.ice` is where you think it is.

Comment: Thanks, i already found the issue, when $(SLICE2CPP) contains white spaces that rule isn't pick, the white spaces confuse make. scape white spaces with "\ " solved my problem.